# The invalid relational operator in this query

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

```
select Bus_no, time
from reaches r
where r.bus_no = 127
having max (hault);
```

When I am trying to check the query in Oracle SQL Developer, it is showing me error as the "invalid relational operator".

Comment: Having is a bit like a WHERE applied to aggregated results (SUM, COUNT, MAX...). You need to write e.g. having max(hault) > 100. You will need the group by clause too, since you are aggregating data.

Answer (score 0):

"Invalid relational operator" indicates a predicate in the query does not resolve to a SQL Condition.

For example, `max(hault)` does *not* mean "find the row with the maximum value of `hault`" as you might have intended. `max(hault)` is an expression (in this case, an aggregate function) that returns the maximum value of `hault`.

A value on its own cannot be used as a condition in a query (in the where or having clause). To become a valid condition, you must apply a relational operator such as a comparison operator (`=`, `!=`, `<>`, `^=`, `<`, `<=`, `>`, `>=`, `BETWEEN`, `NOT BETWEEN`, `LIKE`, `NOT LIKE`, `REGEXP_LIKE`, `IS NULL`, `IS NOT NULL`, etc.) or a set operator (`IN`, `NOT IN`, `EXISTS`, `NOT EXISTS`).

SQL Conditions reference:
https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlqr/SQL-Conditions.html#GUID-857D67A8-9224-4C71-88A2-4869696F1A1C

About SQL Conditions:
https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/About-SQL-Conditions.html#GUID-E9EC8434-CD48-4C01-B01B-85E5359D8DD7